# Irreducibility of analytic varieties

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $V$ be an analytic variety and $V^{*}$ denote the locus of its smooth points. From Griffiths & Harris, page 21, we have that an analytic variety $V$ is irreducible iff $V^{*}$ is connected.

When the converse is proven, he defines the function $$g = \alpha \cdot f + \beta \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_{n}}$$ What exactly is the motivation for defining such a function in this way? We are trying to construct some polynomial $f_{i}$ which is holomorphic and vanishes on the set $\bar{V}_{i}$. In addition, I understand that he defines the polynomial $f_{i}$ using elementary symmetric functions in the form $(z_{n} - \omega_{\nu 1})...(z_{n} - \omega_{\nu l})$ where $\omega_{\nu}$ denotes the $z_{n}$- coordinates of $\pi^{-1}(z')$. So in this case, why does f vanish on this set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a claim in the book, page 13(the second property of analytic variety); basically, it says that, in a good coordinate, the image of $Z(f,\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_n})$ under the projection $\pi:\mathbb C^n\longrightarrow \mathbb C^{n-1}$ is exactly the zeros of $g$ in $\mathbb C^{n-1}$. This implies, by the implicit function theorem, $Z(f)$ is a branched covering over $\Delta^{n-1}$ and the branched points are exactly the zeros of $g$. Therefore, for fixed $z'$ in $\Delta^{n-1}-\{g=0\}$, the polynomial $f$ has distinct roots then we can construct the symmetric polynomial of the roots.

Comment: If $f$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[z,w]$ and $U$ is a domain in $\mathbb{C}^2$, then does it imply that the variety $V=Z(f) \cap U$ is an irreducible variety?